# KQL window functions - how to partition by multiple columns?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Input table dimVehicleV1:

| SaleStart | Product | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | Car | 1 |
| 1/2/2020 | Bike | 1 |
| 2/1/2020 | Car | 2 |
| 3/1/2020 | Bike | 2 |

Desired output dimVehicleV2:

| SaleStart | Product | Model | SaleEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | Car | 1 | 2/1/2020 |
| 1/2/2020 | Bike | 1 | 3/1/2020 |
| 2/1/2020 | Car | 2 | null |
| 3/1/2020 | Bike | 2 | null |

I see serialization via order by, and then the next() function. I don't see how to make it respect the Product column groupings though.

Fail query:

```
let dimVehicleV2 =
dimVehicleV1
| order by Product asc, SaleStart asc
| extend SaleEnd = next(SaleStart, 1);
dimVehicleV2
```

How does one use the next() function so that it respects column groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should work:

```
datatable(SaleStart:datetime, Product:string, Model:int)
[
    datetime(1/1/2020), 'Car',  1,
    datetime(1/2/2020), 'Bike', 1,
    datetime(2/1/2020), 'Car',  2,
    datetime(3/1/2020), 'Bike', 2,
]
| order by Product asc, SaleStart asc
| extend SaleEnd = iff(next(Product) == Product and next(Model) != Model, next(SaleStart), datetime(null))
```

| SaleStart | Product | Model | SaleEnd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Car | 1 | 2020-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00.0000000 | Bike | 1 | 2020-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
| 2020-02-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Car | 2 |  |
| 2020-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Bike | 2 |  |

Comment: Ah so manually examine the rows - thank you!

Would be nice if next() took on a parameter PartitionByColumnList to handle this - in the case of high-granularity tables with many cols to do this with, it gets tedious.

Answer (score 4):

I came to this post searching for an answer to the question actually in the title of this post: "How to partition by multiple columns?"

In case someone else needs, here is what I ended up doing: `extend` the domain by creating a new column that combines the values of the multiple columns you want, and use that new column as the partition key.

You can combine the columns by using concatenation, or a hash, or something else.

```
dimVehicleV1
| extend PartitionKey = strcat(Product, ":", Model)
| partition hint.strategy=native by PartitionKey (top 1 by SaleStart) // or wharever partition transformation
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing before coming to this answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case useful to anyone, I found a solution I prefer over Yoni's perfectly adequate one.

```
let MyTable = datatable(SaleStart:datetime, Product:string, Model:int)
[
    datetime(1/1/2020), 'Car',  1,
    datetime(1/2/2020), 'Bike', 1,
    datetime(2/1/2020), 'Car',  2,
    datetime(3/1/2020), 'Bike', 2,
];
MyTable
| partition by Product
    (
       order by Model asc
        | extend SaleEnd = next(SaleStart)
    )
```

This seems to me to abstract away the details of the logic required, expressing just the thought.